# Is the apache running on Event MPM although Event MPM not mentioned in 'Compiled in modules'?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, debian-jessie

I used `apache2 -l` in order to determine which Apache MPM is compiled. The output is:

```
 Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

Then, I run `apache2ctl -M` wich shows `mpm_event_module (shared)` and `a2query -M` which outputs `event`.

The question, is the apache running on Event MPM although there is no Event MPM in 'Compiled in modules'?

Comment: lots of unneeded compiled-in modules there. I wonder why you have so many, generally core, mod_so and http_core should just be compiled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from apache 2.4 onwards, mpm's can be compiled as modules, unlike previous apache versions where you were forced to choose mpm during compilation and had to recompile apache to eventually switch mpm.

Note that you can't have the same module built both statically, inside sbin/httpd with can be seen from `apache2 -l` and dynamically as a `.so` file inside the `modules` directory which you can see with apache2 -M.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know, why Event MPM is not listed in the 'Compiled in modules'?

Comment: Because it's built as a module. You can choose to compile some module statically so it'll be inside the httpd binnary, or as a dynamically loaded module, like the onles inside $APACHE_ROOT/modules/ directory. Obviously you can't have the same module built both statically and dinamically.
Ok, I'll update my answer with this info.